# Different version of npm when using sudo?

Tags: node.js, linux, npm, fedora

when I tried to update npm, I found that command returns Permission deny:

```
npm install npm -g
```

Then I tried:

```
sudo npm install npm -g
```

Then npm has been updated, but when I tried npm -v and sudo npm -v, they show different version:

```
npm -v //3.10.10
sudo npm -v //5.1.0
```

How can I make them always in the same version? It also happened on command 'node -v'. I am using fedora.

Comment: I'd grep / awk node in your root directory to see how many instances you find - might be the case that node command is set up to read from dir A and then sudo npm is using dir B

Comment: Just type grep node? It seems take a long time

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, I will try them

Comment: @qwang yeah it will, but it means you can see everywhere node is (maybe try making more specific to nodejs and search nodejs) and see if there are any conflicts

Comment: @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs I tried whereis command. It shows one is in /usr/bin and the other one is in /usr/local/bin. However, when I try to remove and reinstall, I can only remove using sudo, and it only remove the one in the /usr/bin. How to remove the other one in /usr/local/bin?